# Append post thumbnail timage to the first content heading tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add new conditions to the following code:

```php
function add_thumb_after_h2( $content ) {
  if (is_single()) {
    global $post;

    if ( substr_count( $content, '<h2>' ) > 3 ) {
      $thumb = '<div id="post_thumbnail">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'fullsize' ) . '</div>';
      $content = str_replace_once("</h2>", "</h2>".$thumb, $content);
    }
  }

  return $content;
}
```

I also need to include `h3`, `h4` and `h5`, example:

```php
    if ( substr_count( $content, '<h2>,<h3>,<h4>,<h5>' ) > 3 ) {}
```

How can I do it?
The thumbnail should be added only to the first occurrence of a heading tag, regardless of its type (`h2`, `h3`, etc.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this my modifying your function to the following:

```php
function add_thumb_after_h2( $content ) {
  if ( is_single() ) {
    global $post;

    foreach ( array('h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5') as $heading ) {
      if ( ! $replaced && substr_count( $content, "<{$heading}>" ) > 3 ) {
        $thumb = '<div id="post_thumbnail">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'fullsize' ) . '</div>';
        $content = str_replace_once("</{$heading}>", "</{$heading}>" . $thumb, $content);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine but duplicates the h1.
P.S. I am not a programmer. Sorry.

Comment: To receive a more relevant answers, please explain in more detail what are you trying to achieve with your code. In the original question there is noting about `<h1>` tag.

Comment: The function does what is expected.
The problem is that in some cases, it adds the thumbnail below the first h2, and below the h3 and several vacancies.
It should only be added under the first h2 once.

Comment: @Edns I have updated my answer and have included the `break` statement - this way it will stop replacing after the first found heading.

Comment: @Edns can you accept/flag my answer as the correct one for this question?